# Adding a contact form to MediaWiki

Tags: html, javascript

There are a few contact form extensions for MediaWiki that one can download and install but I don't want to use extensions at all (or changing the PHP) if there is another solution in HTML-Javascript.

Is there any HTML-JavaScript module I could utilize?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are in general two extensions doing this:

- the simpler one is https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:EmailForm
- the more sophisticated one would be https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:FormMailer

The first one seems to be easier to implement - the whole code is hosted on the Wiki page, where the form should appear. Just insert, adjust to your needs and you are done.

On usage of the second one you should insert into your form's code certain functional variables, listed on the extension's page.